# SQL create table not working due to errors

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE Patient(
pAdminNumber int NOT NULL,
dID int NOT NULL,
wID int NOT NULL,
pName VARCHAR(50),
DOB DATE,
pGender CHAR(10),
pAddress VARCHAR(50),
pTelephone VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(pAdminNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(dID)
REFERNCES Doctor(dID),
FOREIGN KEY(wID)
REFERNECES Ward(wID)
);
```

I am trying to run this sql code however it keeps giving errors. The other two which i ran executed successfully.

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor(
dID int NOT NULL,
wID int NOT NULL,
dName VARCHAR(50),
DOB DATE,
dYearsWorked int,
PRIMARY KEY(dID),
FOREIGN KEY(wID)
REFERENCES Ward(wID)
);

CREATE TABLE Ward(
wID int NOT NULL,
wName VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (wID) 
);
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: "Not working" won't help us help you.  What's the error????  That's the most important piece of information you can give.  "Not working" means nothing to us.

Comment: What errors? Remove half of the columns. Does the error still exist? Try other halp of what's left etc.

Comment: Mispeeled "REFERNECES" and "REFERNCES". Next time share the error as it probably says exactly what the problem is. Voting to close as "Simple typographical error".

Answer (score 1):

here's a guess

```
CREATE TABLE Patient(
pAdminNumber int NOT NULL,
dID int NOT NULL,
wID int NOT NULL,
pName VARCHAR(50),
DOB DATE,
pGender CHAR(10),
pAddress VARCHAR(50),
pTelephone VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(pAdminNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(dID)
REFERENCES Doctor(dID),
FOREIGN KEY(wID)
REFERENCES Ward(wID)
);
```

check your spelling: REFERENCES

Comment: I am very new at this and this is very embarrassing thanks guys SOS

Answer (score 1):

On the foreign keys for Patient, `REFERENCES` is mispelled as `'REFERNCES'`, it should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient
    ( pAdminNumber int NOT NULL, 
      dID int NOT NULL, 
      wID int NOT NULL, 
      pName VARCHAR(50), 
      DOB DATE, 
      pGender CHAR(10), 
      pAddress VARCHAR(50), 
      pTelephone VARCHAR(50), 
      PRIMARY KEY(pAdminNumber), 
      FOREIGN KEY(dID) REFERENCES Doctor(dID), 
      FOREIGN KEY(wID) REFERENCES Ward(wID) 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

check the Spelling of REFERENCES keyword, i believe you have misspelled it

CREATE TABLE Ward(
wID int NOT NULL,
wName VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (wID) 
);

CREATE TABLE Doctor(
dID int NOT NULL,
wID int NOT NULL,
dName VARCHAR(50),
DOB DATE,
dYearsWorked int,
PRIMARY KEY(dID),
FOREIGN KEY(wID)
REFERENCES Ward(wID)
);

CREATE TABLE Patient(pAdminNumber int NOT NULL,
dID int NOT NULL,
wID int NOT NULL,
pName VARCHAR(50),
DOB DATE,
pGender CHAR(10),
pAddress VARCHAR(50),
pTelephone VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(pAdminNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(dID) REFERENCES Doctor(dID),
FOREIGN KEY(wID) REFERENCES Ward(wID)
);

Answer (score 0):

SQL code has spelling error for REFERENCES, below is correct:

```
 CREATE TABLE Patient(
pAdminNumber int NOT NULL,
dID int NOT NULL,
wID int NOT NULL,
pName VARCHAR(50),
DOB DATE,
pGender CHAR(10),
pAddress VARCHAR(50),
pTelephone VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(pAdminNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(dID)
REFERENCES Doctor(dID),
FOREIGN KEY(wID)
REFERENCES Ward(wID)
);
```